# How to use variable as background image from textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

at the moment I am struggling to figure out this problem.
I am attempting to make a textbox set the background of the website.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Enter URL: <input type="text" id="myText">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Set Wallpaper</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  document.body.style.background = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect the content of the textbox to be?

Answer (score 2):

CSS `background` property only accepts values in some defined format.

You can use some predefined colors i.e. `green` or `red`

```js
document.body.style.background = 'green';
```

or use some image

```js
let img_url = 'path_to.jpg';
document.body.style.background = `url(${img_url})`;
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background for more info

Answer (score -2):

Well, u cannot simply set your background as text, that's weird. If u want to set it from url and have the image on the bg, then try something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  document.body.style = 'background-image: url(${x});';
}
```

Comment: This overrides all other styles on the element.